# can I Call startSearch from a nonSearchable activity - Android?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have one activity I want to use for all search results for an app. If I call `startSearch(..)` from another activity I do not see the intent at all.  If I call the function from the searchable activity it seems to work. I kind of suspect my manifest: Am I missing something?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.wfs.android.youtubelistoptimizerforandroid" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NETWORK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <!-- enable the search dialog to send searches to SearchableActivity -->
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
        android:value=".SearchableActivity" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.wfs.android.youtubelistoptimizerforandroid.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >


        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <service
        android:name="com.wfs.android.youtubelistoptimizerforandroid.UploadService"
        android:exported="true" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.wfs.android.youtubelistoptimizerforandroid.PlayActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_play"
        android:parentActivityName="com.wfs.android.youtubelistoptimizerforandroid.MainActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.wfs.android.youtubelistoptimizerforandroid.ReviewActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_review"
        android:parentActivityName="com.wfs.android.youtubelistoptimizerforandroid.MainActivity" />

    <activity android:name=".SearchActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_search">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This change to the manifest fixed me: it needs the full name of the class to pass the search intent to.

```
 <!-- enable the search dialog to send searches to SearchableActivity -->
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
        android:value="com.wfs.android.youtubelistoptimizerforandroid.SearchActivity" />
```

This is from the Google documentation:

```
 <!-- enable the search dialog to send searches to SearchableActivity -->
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
               android:value=".SearchableActivity" />
</activity>
```